# Unable to browse to anything other than the main URL on a new Laravel Apache2 setup. ERROR: The requested URL was not found on this server

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, apache2, virtualhost

I've set up a new Laravel site with an Apache2 webserver and have mimicked the setup of a similar working site, on the same server, but every time i browse to a URL which is example.com/*anything* it gives me a 404 page not found error. The main site url works, but no pages are accessible.

Eg:

- example.com {{ This works fine }}
- example.com/home {{ Errors with page cannot be found }}
- example.com/anything-i-put-here {{ Errors with page cannot be found }}

The site works fine on other servers and locally, so im certain its not the Laravel site itself thats broken. Another laravel site on the same server with basically identical setup (as far as i can see) works fine, so I know the server itself is set up correctly and is serving other sites.

I'm fairly new to apache2 virtual server setup, so im pretty sure i've just not configured this correctly. I've been trawling through the internet and have read so so many posts reccomending people to set up the apache2.conf and the .htaccess files basically exactly the same as i have them, so im at a bit of a loss. Has anyone got any suggestions?

apache config file (symlinked in sites-enabled):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    Redirect 301 / https://example.com/
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
     DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public_html/public
     ServerName example.com

     <Directory /var/www/example.com/public_html/public>
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymlinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
#       SSLRequireSSL
     </Directory>
     <FilesMatch \.php$>
         SetHandler "proxy:unix:/var/www/example.com/fpm/php7.2-example.sock|fcgi://localhost/"
     </FilesMatch>
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile path/to/key.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile path/to/key.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

.htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

and yes, modrewrite is enabled

Comment: Where is the `.htaccess` file located? I would certainly remove the `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` wrapper incase this is masking an error (it's not needed anyway). Are you requesting HTTPS version of your site? When you request `example.com/` (ie. the site root) it does not require anything in `.htaccess` - so this may explain why this works.

Comment: It seems a bit silly that you enable MultiViews in the server config, only to disable it again in `.htaccess`. It should just be disabled from the get-go in the server config. `site-url.com` or `my-site-url.com`? You've used both, is this 2 separate domains? - please use `example.com` thoughout (as per [RFC2606](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2606#section-3)) if this refers to a single domain.

Comment: Hi MrWhite. Thanks for your comments. The .htaccess file is in /var/www/example.com/public_html/public. The same place as the index.php file. Im pretty certain this is the correct place for a Laravel site. This is where its on another working Laravel installation on the same server.

I was under the impression that the mod_rewrite wrapper was used to add in the omitted index.php. I could be wrong though, this isnt really my forte.

I'm requesting an https version of the site so http should redirect to https.

When you say 'it doesnt really require anything in .htaccess' what do you mean?

Comment: Yeah sorry, i was testing a few things out from other approaches, hence adding the MultiViews where it wast needed, so ive reverted this line back to its original ```Options -Indexes +FollowSymlinks +MultiViews``` in the apache config.

I've updated the urls to example.com to disambiguate this. Theres only one domain in question here.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code in your `.htaccess` after `RewriteEngine On`

`RewriteBase /`

So your `.htaccess` should look like the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: If the `.htaccess` file is already in the document root (which is where it should be), then setting `RewriteBase /` is not going to change anything.

Comment: I have faced this issue and solved it like this. Let's see if OP's project works.

Comment: Hi Rian. Thanks for the suggestion. I've tried adding RewriteBase / as per your suggestion and restarted apache, but i'm still getting the same issue.